# While loop doing something while waiting for a message

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a program that waits for a UDP message,

is there a way to do something while it is waiting for a UDP message?

So the program does something but as soon as it receives a message it goes and does something else?

thanks

Comment: The answer to your question is: Yes, it is possible

Comment: do you know a good way how?

Comment: If you want to do something else until you receive the message, then you do not want to wait. You want to get notified (by an event). Start a listener thread that waits for the message and then publish that through a messenger.

Comment: do you think the BeginReceive function works?

Answer (score 0):

```
while (true)
        {
            counter += 1;
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for connection...");
            clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
            Console.WriteLine(" >> " + "Client No:" + Convert.ToString(counter) + " started!");
            handleClinet client = new handleClinet();
            client.startClient(clientSocket, Convert.ToString(counter));
        }
```

Reference: http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-multi-threaded-server-socket.htm

**UPDATE:** if you want your main thread to be free and create another thread to wait for connections read this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/463947/Working-with-Sockets-in-Csharp

```
String theMessageToReceive = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);
    while (senderSock.Available > 0)
    {
      bytesRec = senderSock.Receive(bytes);
      theMessageToReceive += Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);
    // Do something
    }
```

Comment: If you debug the program, the `while` will start and stop at the third line (waiting for a connection) then a new thread will be created to communicate with this client (`handleClient`) while the server wait for more.

Comment: Okay but I don't want to wait for more messages, I just want to create a while loop that does something else when their is no messag received

Comment: So you want a server that wait for connections in a different thread, so the main thread is free to do whatever you want, I recommend you to edit your question because it's not so clear and read this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/463947/Working-with-Sockets-in-Csharp

Comment: There's a link at the end where you can download the project and see the entire code.

Comment: Well, I edited my answer with the part you receive the message.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, multiple while-loops aren't multithreading.
C# is a language that works itself from top to the bottom through code.
Second:

```
//create new worker
public System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker worker;
// Start new thread
private void StartBackgroundWorker (...) {...}
//what should the worker do
private void worker_DoWork (...) {...}
//if the progress has changed while working
private void worker_ProgressChanged (...) {...}
//thread is finished
private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted (...) {...}
```

These are all methods needed (and maybe a bit more) for that task.
But I think you should start a bit lower while learning C#.